# Integration to calculate expected value for a distribution

Tags: integration, monte-carlo

I am currently learning Monte Carlo integration, I am completely lost on how to calculate the expected value of the following, before I simulate it using Monte Carlo.

$R0 = px + (1-p)exp(\epsilon +x)$

where x has a $Beta(3,1)$ distribution where B(3,1) = 1/3.

I can calculate $P(X=x) = 3x^2$ using the pmf of a beta distribution, but i get lost when it comes to using this in the integration alongside $\epsilon$.

I know the output is know that the output is $E[R0]=3(p/4+(1−p)(exp(ϵ+1)−2exp(ϵ)))$ but I have no idea what steps were taken to get there.

Am more than happy to take general integration guidance / sources to learn from - havnt been able to find this specific problem anywhere and am trying to work through each step to learn.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does the (rather complicated) random variable $R_0 := pX+ (1-p)\exp(\epsilon +X)$ with $X$ (note the capital letter) following a Beta distr. come from a book ? (btw: what is $\epsilon$ ?). You must know that Monte Carlo simulations are mainly used in cases where we don't know previously the characterisitic values (mean, variance, etc.)

Comment: Its from a lecture - I actually know that the output is $E[R0] = 3(p/4+(1-p)(exp(\epsilon+1)-2exp(\epsilon)))$ - but i dont know how to get there. Ill add it to the Q.